# Grails accessing controller values from view

Tags: javascript, ajax, grails, view, controller

I am quite new to Grails, so please bear with me.

My view has javascript code likes this:

```
//js code in my View
function validateEmailAndSetEmail(){
    var result =${remoteFunction(controller:'myController',action:'validateEmail',update:'responseDiv', params:'\'email=\'+document.getElementById(\'email\').value')};

    if (result) { //doSomething}
}
```

and my controller looks like:

```
def validateEmail = {
    def emailToValidate = request.getParameter("email")
    def matchingEmailFound = myService.checkEmailAddress(emailToValidate)

    if (matchingEmailFound){
        render "This email is already in use.<br>If you have already created an account with this email, please try to reset the password from Login page."}
    else{
        //setEmail to send here
        render "This email is not in use. This email will be used as your account email"}

    return !matchingEmailFound
```

My question has two parts:

1. when I examine the value of *result* in my js code from firebug, it is
   not boolean type(true/false) and the value seems to be incorrect, would there be any way to pass this value
   correctly to js in the view from controller?
2. Would I be able to call set email value to some variable in
   controller and call that outside of js in my view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remeber that Ajax is asynchronous - your `if(result)` is executed as soon as the remote call has been sent, not when it has completed.

A better approach would be to change your controller action to return some JSON data:

```
def model = [matchFound:matchingEmailFound]
if(matchingEmailFound) {
  model.message = "This email is already in use.<br>If you have already created an account with this email, please try to reset the password from Login page."
} else {
  model.message = "This email is not in use. This email will be used as your account email"
}
render (model as JSON)
```

Then on the client side use an `onSuccess` function instead of the update.

```
${remoteFunction(controller:'myController',action:'validateEmail',
   params:'\'email=\'+document.getElementById(\'email\').value', onSuccess:'checkEmail(e)')};
```

and define

```
function checkEmail(response) {
  var r = JSON.parse(response.text);
  $('responseDiv').innerHTML = r.message;
  if(r.matchFound) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I'm not a JavaScript expert but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great. Except I changed 
  $('responseDiv').innerHTML = r.message;
 to var r = eval('('+response.responseText+')');

Comment: var r = JSON.parse(response.text); to var r = eval('('+response.responseText+')');

Comment: And $('responseDiv').innerHTML = r.message; to $('responseDiv').update(r.message);